# What is the limit $x\to\infty$?

Tags: limits, filters

I'm working on some exercises about bases of filters and in one of them they want me to compare the bases $x\to+\infty, x\to-\infty$ and $x\to\infty$. I know that I could take the base $\{(x,+\infty):x\in\mathbb{R}\}$ for $x\to+\infty$ and in an analogous manner for $x\to-\infty$. My question is what means $x\to\infty$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base(bases of filter) for $x \to \infty$ is $U(\infty) = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}\colon \delta \lt |x| \}$ where $\delta \in \mathbb{R}$ - Vladimir A. Zorich - Mathematical Analysis I-Springer (2016), page 127.

Comment: thank you. I was thinking on that but i was not sure